# mysql where IN statement using regex?

Tags: mysql

What is the best way to do this?

```
select * from myTable where hostname IN ('host1-%', 'host2-%', 'host3-%')
```

where host name sometimes come back as fully qualified domain or simple as just host1

Comment: `WHERE hostname LIKE 'host1-%' OR hostname LIKE 'host2-%' OR hostname LIKE 'host3-%'`

Answer (score 3):

Does this do what you want

```
select * from myTable where hostname REGEXP '^host[123]-'
```

or

```
select * from myTable where hostname REGEXP '^host[1-3]-'
```

Comment: You need `^` anchor at the beginning, you don't need `.*` at the end.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that - missed the ^ on cut & paste & automatically converted % to .* without thinking it is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

To add to PaulF's answer, you might need to make use of `LIKE` in conjunction with `REGEXP`, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE hostname LIKE 'host%' AND hostname REGEXP '^host[1-3]-'
```

This is because MySQL doesn't make use of indexes when processing `REGEXP`, but it will use it for `LIKE` when the pattern has a constant prefix. So if you have an index on the `hostname` column, this will use the index to narrow down to `hostXXX`, then only have to perform a regular expression match on those rows.

See [Mysql optimization for REGEXP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318083/mysql-optimization-for-regexp)